# .htaccess redirection, URLs with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a problem with creation a redirect 301 through htaccess for pages with parameters.
I want to redirect all pages in one directory to the homepage of another (the new URLs are without parameters and have a different structure so I just want to redirect to the main section)

It means - I have now

```
http://www.mysite.com/old_directory/page.php?s=12345
```

etc... and all of them I want to redirect to

```
http://www.mysite.com/new_directory/
```

How should I modify this redirect? Its Apache server and Wordpress platform.

Comment: To be clear, you want to redirect everything from `old_directory` to `new_directory` and include URL parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you end the substitution string with just a question mark, it will erase an existing query string. [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

`RewriteRule ^/old_directory/.* /new_directory/? [R=301,L]`

Comment: You'll want a ? at the end: `/new_directory/?` Otherwise the query string will automatically get appended.

Comment: Oops, that was the most important part. Thanks.